# Weird Binned Boxplot When Running RStudio on Mac OS X

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse

I'm trying to learn R on my own and a doing my best to follow along the 'R for Data Science' book from O'Reilly.

I've made it to an exercise where I want to create a binned boxplot plot of a subset of data from the 'Diamonds' data set in the 'Tidyverse' package. When I run the code in Bootcamp (Windows 10) I get the result I expect with vertical boxplots in the set bin width. When I run it in Mac OS the boxplot appears to be horizontal and I can't for the life of me figure out why! See my result here: [image: Funky Boxplot when Running RStudio in Mac]

I'm sure there are folks who will say just work in Windows, but my stubborn 2016 Macbook Pro in Windows 10 mode doesn't like connecting to my external, wired monitor. The monitor works perfectly in Mac mode though, so I don't really care to sink any more time into figuring out why the monitor connection is so unreliable in Windows 10 mode.

Personal problems aside, below is the identical code I've been using in RStudio for Mac and Windows modes. Attached/linked above is the output plot I'm getting when I run RStudio in Mac. The boxplots should be oriented vertically. Hoping someone can help me understand how to fix this weird occurrence when running RStudio and R in Mac mode!

Sorry if referring to mac/windows as different 'modes of operation' is incorrect. That's the only way I know to convey the difference!

Here's my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
smaller <- diamonds %>% filter(carat<3) # just want to see carats less than 3

ggplot(data=smaller,mapping=aes(x=carat,y=price))+ 
  geom_boxplot(mapping=aes(group=cut_width(carat,0.1)))
```

Comment: The carat attribute is numeric - that is why your plot looks that way.

Comment: I think that’s intent of the exercise. It’s to be able to ‘fake’ a categorical variable given numeric variables by binning the data.

Answer (score 0):

In R-devel under linux I get the same result.

It works, though, if you do:

```r
library(tidyverse)
smaller <- diamonds %>% filter(carat<3) # just want to see carats less than 3
ggplot(smaller, aes(x=carat,y=price))+ 
    geom_boxplot(aes(x=cut_width(carat, .1)))
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could just plot it like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
diamonds %>% filter(carat<3) %>% 
    mutate(carat = cut_width(carat,0.1)) %>% 
    ggplot(., aes(x=carat, y=price))+ geom_boxplot()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much! I’ll give that alternate a try and see what happens.